# Snapshot failed, now hanging on delete

Tags: google-compute-engine

Tried to run a snapshot from the developer console and it failed. Then tried to delete the snapshot and it's just hanging.

Stopped and started the instance didn't change things, snapshot delete still hanging.

How can I clear this problem? I haven't run a snapshot for 6 months and there are 2 earlier snapshots of the disk, I was expecting to perform a simple incremental snapshot.

Comment: Have now successfully deleted the failed snapshot and created a new one. I wonder if this coincides with the fix Adrian indicated in his answer?

Answer (score 0):

It might be related to a known issue and we are working on the fix.

I'll update this answer once the fix goes into production.

**UPDATE**

The issue I mentioned was solved on 15th May around 06:00 GMT. All snapshots that were stuck in PENDING status should be in FAILED status. After retrying to delete the snapshot, the snapshot should be deleted.

I suppose you were affected by this issue. Anyway, I'm glad to hear you were able to delete the snapshot.