# Can't Delete Google Cloud Snapshot

Tags: google-compute-engine, snapshot

I had a VM running on Google cloud.
I created a Snapshot of that VM , While it was busy been creating the Snapshot.

I deleted the VM.

When Trying to Delete the Snapshot, I get the following error

> The deletion of some of the snapshots failed. Error: The resource 'projects/project-ID/global/snapshots/dbserver' is not ready

Answer (score 0):

As I said in another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30209474/snapshot-failed-now-hanging-on-delete/30214776#30214776), there was a issue with some snapshots by the time you posted your error message.

The issue has been solved. Could you retry to delete it and confirm if it works? Otherwise, could you post your project ID so I can open a ticket on your behalf?

Thanks!